# jquery add div with class not working

Tags: c#, android

If there is no content within `div.deletePhone` then you need to specify the height or else it will be `0px`.

```
#div1 ul li .deletePhone{
background-image:  url(http://localhost/TheEatTel/public/images/close.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:100px; /*some height value*/
}
```

That or put `var phone` in `div.deletePhone`:

```
$("#div1 ul").append("<li><div class='deletePhone'>"+phone+"</div></li>");
```

Comment: deletePhone = deleteFood ?

Comment: Where's `.deleteFood`?

Comment: sorry it is just an error in writing, the problem still

Comment: Does `http://localhost/TheEatTel/public/images/close.png` point to a valid PNG resource?

Comment: Why is your image url not in quotes?

Comment: @DiMono It doesn't need to be

Comment: @Evan Yes, but good form

Comment: Not added, or not visible? Different animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no content within `div.deletePhone` then you need to specify the height or else it will be `0px`.

```
#div1 ul li .deletePhone{
background-image:  url(http://localhost/TheEatTel/public/images/close.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:100px; /*some height value*/
}
```

That or put `var phone` in `div.deletePhone`:

```
$("#div1 ul").append("<li><div class='deletePhone'>"+phone+"</div></li>");
```

Comment: Sounds like it's supposed to be a number and a phone icon next to it.  If the icon is the same height as the text, you could also just throw a space in the content of `.deletePhone`: `<div class="deletePhone">&nbsp;</div>`